# using for loop to store value of html element into an array and display in another element

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have this add button which adds rows in my table. I've a column which displays price of elements selected. But after adding new row I want to display the price of selected item in the Unit price column and total column.

I've tried to store the values in an array but the unit price section and total section is not displaying what i want.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="table-title">
            <div class="row">
                <h2><u>Select <b>Products</b></h2></u>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add-new pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form action="">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>P N</th>
                            <th>H.C</th>
                            <th>So</th>
                            <th>Qt</th>
                            <th>Unit Price ₹ Per kg</th>
                            <th>Total ₹</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <select id="myInput " class="browser-default custom-select form-control">
                                        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                                        <option value="one">One</option>
                                        <option value="two">Two</option>
                                        <option value="three">Three</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn pull-right" onclick="myFunction()" type="button">See Price</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Auto Generated>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="dropdown ">
                                        <select class=" browser-default custom-select form-control ">
                                            <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                                            <option value="p1 ">Water</option>
                                            <option value="p2 ">Oil </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" id="myQty" type="number" value="" defauft="0"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <p id="price ">₹ 00/kg</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p id="total" value="">₹ 00/Kg</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="add " title="Add " data-toggle="tooltip "><i class="material-icons ">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                                    <a class="delete " title="Delete " data-toggle="tooltip "><i class="material-icons ">&#xE872;</i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="thanks.html "><button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn-warning sp pull-right " type="button ">Place Order <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right "></i></button></a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function myFunction() {
    var text;
    var price = document.getElementById("myInput ");
    var strProducts = price.options[price.selectedIndex].text;
    switch (strProducts) {
        case "One":
        text = 500;
        break;
        case "Two":
        text = 400;
        break;
        case "Three":
        text = 300;
        break;
        default:
        text = 00;
    }
    document.getElementById("price ").innerHTML = text;
    var number = document.getElementById("myQty").value;
    if (number == "") {
        var totall = 1 * text;
    } else {
        var totall = number * text;
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totall;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code to add row?

Comment: JavaScript to add rows:  https://slack-files.com/TLJ6H3YN4-FLMD987RT-c46552e748

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for you query:

You made the mistake in selecting the wrong element for input var which should be type number not type= text

```
var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="number"]');
```

```js
// Add row on add button click
$(document).on("click", ".add", function() {

    var empty = false;

    var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="number"]');
    input.each(function() {

        if (!$(this).val()) {

            $(this).addClass("error");

            empty = true;

        } else {

            $(this).removeClass("error");

        }

    });

    $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();

    if (!empty) {
        console.log(input.length);
        input.each(function(index,value) {

            $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());

        });

        $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();

        $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");

    }

});

// Edit row on edit button click

$(document).on("click", ".edit", function() {

    $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();

    $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");

});

// Delete row on delete button click

$(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {

    $(this).parents("tr").remove();

    $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");

});



function myFunction() {
    var text;
    var price = document.getElementById("myInput ");
    var strProducts = price.options[price.selectedIndex].text;
    switch (strProducts) {
        case "One":
            text = 500;
            break;
        case "Two":
            text = 400;
            break;
        case "Three":
            text = 300;
            break;
        default:
            text = 00;
    }
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = text;
    var number = document.getElementById("myQty").value;
    if (number == "") {
        var totall = 1 * text;
    } else {
        var totall = number * text;
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = totall;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="table-title">
            <div class="row">
                <h2><u>Select <b>Products</b></h2></u>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add-new pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form action="">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>P N</th>
                            <th>H.C</th>
                            <th>So</th>
                            <th>Qt</th>
                            <th>Unit Price ₹ Per kg</th>
                            <th>Total ₹</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <select id="myInput " class="browser-default custom-select form-control">
                                        <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                                        <option value="one">One</option>
                                        <option value="two">Two</option>
                                        <option value="three">Three</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn pull-right" onclick="myFunction()" type="button">See Price</button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <Auto Generated>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="dropdown ">
                                        <select class=" browser-default custom-select form-control ">
                                            <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
                                            <option value="p1 ">Water</option>
                                            <option value="p2 ">Oil </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" id="myQty" type="number" value="" defauft="0"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <p id="price">₹ 00/kg</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <p id="total" value="">₹ 00/Kg</p>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="add " title="Add " data-toggle="tooltip "><i class="material-icons ">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                                    <a class="delete " title="Delete " data-toggle="tooltip "><i class="material-icons ">&#xE872;</i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="thanks.html "><button class="btn btn--radius-2 btn-warning sp pull-right " type="button ">Place Order <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right "></i></button></a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```